# Qt - register multiple signals that when they've all emitted produce a giant signal connected to one slot

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals, signals-slots, slots

In my application I have the following situation:

- an object emits signal `removeCharacter`
- `removeCharacter` has a part A and B, and after part A is done it fires signal `removePath`
- slot `onRemovePath` is connected to signal `removePath` and will remove the path for the character and then fire a signal `pathRemoved`
- slot `finishRemovingCharacter` is connected to signal `pathRemoved` and will finish the rest of the character removal process
- I don't want to always execute this `finishRemovingCharacter` logic when I fire the `removePath` signal

Is there some generic way to achieve the above, preferably something that Qt may already have available?

EDIT: I was hoping there would be a generic way to specify a sequence of signal and slot processing, instead of needing an intermediate slot to send a signal that it is done so the next step can execute.

Comment: I don't understand: please could you say what you aren't happy about, or what you want to generalise?

Comment: I don't understand the question, perhaps QSignalMapper is what you might want? Or maybe a connection with Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, there are only two ways to handle with the situation.

Option 1:
  Use two signals for the `pathRemoved` event. For example `finishRemovingCharacter` is connected to `pathRemoved` but NOT to `pathRemovedSpecial`.

Option 2:
  Add proper arguments to the `pathRemoved` signal and then in the `finishRemovingCharacter` slot check if it should continue or just ignore this event in which case you'll just `return;`.

Comment: Option 2 sounds like a good idea. I tried passing the finishRemovingCharacter slot as an argument to the signal pathRemoved in hopes that I could directly call whatever slot argument I've passed to onRemovePath but I couldn't correctly get it to compile.